# C hsearch find action always return wrong data value but right key value

Tags: c, hashtable

I am dealing with the **hsearch** function in my progam. I generate my key which is a char *. And the data I stored is an integer.
I always add an element without problem, but when I want to find with

ENTRY *elemp, elem;

**elemp = hsearch(elem, FIND)**.

**elemp->data** is always a wrong value(not the one inserted).

Is there a known issue about that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <search.h>

#define N 1
#define B 0
#define U 2
#define TAILLE 100000

char key[1000];

char* convTableToKeyString(int lignes, int colonnes, int joueur_tour, int  tab[lignes][colonnes]) {
int indice = 0;
switch (joueur_tour) {
    case 0:
        key[indice++] = 'B';
        break;
    case 1:
        key[indice++] = 'N';
        break;
}


for (int i = 0; i < lignes; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colonnes; j++) {
        switch (tab[i][j]) {
            case 0:
                key[indice++] = 'B';
                break;
            case 1:
                key[indice++] = 'N';
                break;
            case 2:
                key[indice++] = 'U';
                break;
        }       

    }
}

key[indice++] = '\0';

return key;
}

 int valeur_configuration(int couleur_tour, int colonnes, int lignes, int tabEchec[lignes][colonnes]) {

ENTRY elem, *elemp;
int res;
int i,j;
int prochain_joueur = couleur_tour == B ? N : B;
int tabCase1[lignes][colonnes], tabCase2[lignes][colonnes], tabCase3[lignes][colonnes]; 
int lose_range = couleur_tour == B ? lignes-1 : 0;
int tabConf[3*colonnes];
int nbreCoupsPossibles = 0;

//generate the key and look if it already exist in the table
elem.key = convTableToKeyString(lignes, colonnes, couleur_tour, tabEchec);
elemp = hsearch(elem, FIND);
if (elemp != NULL) {
    return (int) (elemp->data);
}

/* The value is not present in the hash, so I can calculate it */
//my code logic check the possible moves and add the value in the hash table
for (i = 0; i < lignes; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < colonnes; j++) {

        int front = couleur_tour == B ? i-1 : i+1;
        if (tabEchec[i][j] == couleur_tour) {

            if (j != 0 && tabEchec[front][j-1] == prochain_joueur) {
                /* some operations */
                tabConf[nbreCoupsPossibles++] = valeur_configuration(prochain_joueur, colonnes, lignes, tabCase2);
                if(tabConf[nbreCoupsPossibles-1] ==0) {
                    res = 1;
                    elem.data = (void *) res;
                    elemp = hsearch(elem, ENTER);
                    /* there should be no failures */
                    if (elemp == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    return 1;
                }
            } // if (j != 0 && tabEchec[front][j-1] == prochain_joueur)


            if (j != colonnes-1 && tabEchec[front][j+1] == prochain_joueur) {
                /* some operations */
                tabConf[nbreCoupsPossibles++] = valeur_configuration(prochain_joueur, colonnes, lignes, tabCase3);
                if(tabConf[nbreCoupsPossibles-1] ==0) {
                    res = 1;
                    elem.data = (void *) res;
                    elemp = hsearch(elem, ENTER);
                    /* there should be no failures */
                    if (elemp == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                      
                    return 1;
                }
            } // if (j != colonnes-1 && tabEchec[front][j+1] == prochain_joueur)


            if (tabEchec[front][j] == U) {
                /* some operations */
                tabConf[nbreCoupsPossibles++] = valeur_configuration(prochain_joueur, colonnes, lignes, tabCase1);
                if(tabConf[nbreCoupsPossibles-1] ==0) { 
                    res = 1;
                    elem.data = (void *) res;
                    elemp = hsearch(elem, ENTER);
                    /* there should be no failures */
                    if (elemp == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                  
                    return 1;
                }
            } // if (tabEchec[front][j].couleur == U)


        } // if (tabEchec[i][j] == couleur_tour)
    } // for (j = 0; j < colonnes; j++)
} // for (i = 0; i < lignes; i++)

if(nbreCoupsPossibles == 0) {
    //Haven't move, I lost
    res = 0;
    elem.data = (void *) res;
    elemp = hsearch(elem, ENTER);
    /* there should be no failures */
    if (elemp == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return 0;
}

i = 0;
int maxi = 0;
while (i < nbreCoupsPossibles && tabConf[i] > 0) {
    maxi = maxi > tabConf[i] ? maxi : tabConf[i];
    i++;
}

if (i >= nbreCoupsPossibles) {
    res = -1 * (maxi+1);
    elem.data = (void *) res;
    elemp = hsearch(elem, ENTER);
    /* there should be no failures */
    if (elemp == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return res;
} else {
    maxi = tabConf[i];
    while (i < nbreCoupsPossibles) {
        if (tabConf[i] < 0) {
            maxi = maxi > tabConf[i] ? maxi : tabConf[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    res = -1 * (maxi-1);
    elem.data = (void *) res;
    elemp = hsearch(elem, ENTER);
    elemp = hsearch(elem, FIND);
    /* there should be no failures */
    if (elemp == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return res;
} // if (i >= nbreCoupsPossibles)

return 0;
}


/* Function call first call*/
int main() {
    int n,m,i,j;

    hcreate(TAILLE);

    int colonnes;
    int lignes;

    char b = 'a';   

    scanf("%d", &n);

    scanf("%d", &m);

    int tabPions[n][m];
    char temp[m];
    //Fake : just for flushing scanf internal functions
    scanf("%c", &b);


for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", temp);

    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (temp[j] != 'p' && temp[j] != 'P') tabPions[i][j] = U;
        if (temp[j] == 'p') tabPions[i][j] = N;
        if (temp[j] == 'P') tabPions[i][j] = B;
    }
}

    colonnes = m;
    lignes = n;

    int res = valeur_configuration(B, colonnes, lignes, tabPions);
    printf("%d\n", res);
    hdestroy(); 
}
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and read this: [ask]

Comment: Please provide the code of your current implementation. It's impossible to find the issue otherwise.

Comment: @r3musn0x Hope this help

Comment: @samakhov the code you posted here does not compile.

Comment: @Jabberwocky normally It should compile now. This is an hexapawn game https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexapawn

Comment: @samakhov What is the purpose of this program?

Comment: @YunbinLiu It is an hexapawn. It is a kind of chess game. the program need to calculate the best way of playing for the first player, the white one. At each time, the program got some child configurations depending on possible moves. And with these configurations it calculate the new configuration value.  As it is recursive, at many time the program calculates same configurations more than once. So I need to store intermediate configuration values in a hash. And check for it before each computing. For each return situation, I store the value in the hash

Comment: Can you provide a sample of valid input for this program, and what the corresponding output should be? Maybe 2 inputs with different expected outputs?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley https://samakhov.github.io/Config3x4_minus2      https://samakhov.github.io/Config4x4_11                                https://samakhov.github.io/Config5x5_3

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley  I was not able to format them in the right way on the plateform, sou you can found them there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand the program, but I think I can explain your `hsearch` problem.

You are reusing the global `char key[1000]` buffer for every key. `hsearch` doesn't allow that. When you add an item to the hash table, `hsearch` doesn't make a copy of the key string. It only copies the pointer.

Since you're using the same key buffer for all your ENTERs *and* your FINDs, every key in the hash table matches the one you're looking for, every time, because they're all the same string! Most of them are in the wrong hash bucket, making the result of a lookup somewhat random.

A quick fix would be to do `elem.key = strdup(elem.key)` just before each `ENTER` operation.

If you care about freeing the strings before your program exits, you'll have to work a little harder on the memory management. `hsearch` is not helpful in that area, since it doesn't provide an iterator.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I see what you talk about, so it always the same wich returned me the same value.